# Is ZFC the Minimal Structural Theory that Models R

Tags: set-theory

Is ZFC minimal or "simplest" in the sense that is it is the structural theory with the minimal number of sub-structures that can model R and its "classic" continuity and completeness properties (maybe with CH in tow)?

Comment: @Peter Are you suggesting that there are no logical theories intermediate in strength between PA and ZFC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, ZFC is not a *structure*, it is a *theory*.

But even so, ZFC is by far not a *minimal* theory for developing the usual properties of $\mathbb R$. Among set theories Z suffices (that is, ZFC without Replacement and Choice), and even set theory is much more than is needed.

[Second-order arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_arithmetic) will do for a quite a lot of real analysis, if we're willing to accept some not entirely intuitive codings of, say, continuous functions (but that's really the case for numbers in pure set theory, too), and the few things second-order arithmetic can't express are mostly filled out by third-order arithmetic (which allows speaking about abitrary, even "wild", functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$).

Restricting ourselves further, there are a number of well-studied subtheories of second-order arithmetic that suffice to develop various parts of real analysis; this investigation is known as [reverse mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics).

Comment: Is it OK if I correct the title and the body of the question?